# OpenCV 4.1 Java - contourArea() fails assertion depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S for hull matrix

Tags: java, opencv, contour

I've tried to calculate the hull area from the hull points generated by
`convexHull()`.

I followed the [OpenCV Python tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html) (because there's no Java tutorial) and fiddled around with code completion.

This is the code:

```
Imgproc.findContours(patternEdges, patternContours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
MatOfInt patternHull = new MatOfInt();
Imgproc.convexHull(patternContours.get(0), patternHull);
Imgproc.contourArea(pickPoints(patternContours.get(0), patternHull)); // fails here
```

But this throws the following exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.2) /home/build/git/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:274: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea']
>   at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.contourArea_1(Native Method)
>   at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.contourArea(Imgproc.java:1607)
>   at com.acme.opencv.Test.main(Test.java:94)
> ```

Obviously the matrix internal data type is wrong. But why, and how can I convert it?

I'm using OpenCV 4.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that in Java, the API only implements filling the `MatOfInt`
with the **indices of the original point matrix**.

This is what the [Javadoc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#convexHull-org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint-org.opencv.core.MatOfInt-) (directly generated from the C++ doc) says:

> `hull` Output convex hull. **It is either an integer vector of indices** or
>   vector of points. **In the first case, the hull elements are 0-based indices
>   of the convex hull points in the original array (since the set of convex hull
>   points is a subset of the original point set).** In the second case, hull
>   elements are the convex hull points themselves.
>
> *(Emphasis mine)*

There's no "or". There's only the `MatOfInt`, which is the indices of the
original `Point` matrix.

You could create a new matrix with the picked points via such a helper function:

```
private static MatOfPoint2f pickPoints(MatOfPoint points, MatOfInt indices) {
    Point[] pickedPoints = new Point[indices.rows()];
    int newRow = 0;
    for (int index : indices.toArray()) {
        pickedPoints[newRow++] = new Point(points.get(index, 0));
    }
    return new MatOfPoint2f(pickedPoints);
}
```

And then use it:

```
Imgproc.findContours(patternEdges, patternContours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
MatOfInt patternHullIndices = new MatOfInt();
Imgproc.convexHull(patternContours.get(0), patternHullIndices);
Imgproc.contourArea(pickPoints(patternContours.get(0), patternHull));
```